# converting time in query using to_char

Tags: postback, postgresql-9.2

my query results in a time of:  '9:00 AM'
I must sent this to another program that only recognizes the time of:  09:00am.
I have read the examples of to_char in the postgresql manual, but cannot figure out how to:

remove the space between the time and am/pm and
add a zero (0) before the 9

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle this would do the trick:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'HH12:MIAM') from dual
```

Unfortunately I have no postgresql test box to try it there.

According to [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-formatting.html) documentation it should work the same.